# How to properly type-hint method that returns abstract class implementation result type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a problem with type-hinting the results of my method.
It sends operation to the server, and after the response it returns parsed operation result. Every `ServerOperation` has its' own result type and I need to fetch this type somehow.

```
def send(self, operation: ServerOperation): # what should I return here?
    command = operation.get_command(self.__request_executor.conventions)
    self.__request_executor.execute_command(command)

    if isinstance(operation, ServerOperation):
        return command.result
```

Operation class

```
class ServerOperation(Generic[T]):
@abstractmethod
def get_command(self, conventions: "DocumentConventions") -> RavenCommand[T]:
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

And the simplified `RavenCommand` class

```
class RavenCommand(Generic[ResultClass]):
def __init__(self, result_class: Type[ResultClass] = None):
    self._result_class = result_class
    self.result: Union[None, ResultClass] = None
```

How should i approach this?

Implementation example

```
class GetClientConfigurationOperation(MaintenanceOperation):
def get_command(self, conventions: "DocumentConventions") -> "RavenCommand[GetClientConfigurationOperation.Result]":
    return self.GetClientConfigurationCommand()

class GetClientConfigurationCommand(RavenCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(GetClientConfigurationOperation.Result)

    def is_read_request(self) -> bool:
        return False

    def create_request(self, node: ServerNode) -> requests.Request:
        return requests.Request(method="GET", url=f"{node.url}/databases/{node.database}/configuration/client")

    def set_response(self, response: str, from_cache: bool) -> None:
        if response is None:
            return
        self.result = GetClientConfigurationOperation.Result.from_json(json.loads(response))

class Result:
    def __init__(self, etag: int, configuration: ClientConfiguration):
        self.etag = etag
        self.configuration = configuration

    @staticmethod
    def from_json(json_dict: dict) -> GetClientConfigurationOperation.Result:
        return GetClientConfigurationOperation.Result(
            json_dict["Etag"], ClientConfiguration.from_json(json_dict["Configuration"])
        )
```

Comment: FYI `Union[None, ResultClass]` is commonly known as `Optional[ResultClass]`

Comment: @Anentropic  I didn't notice that Union, thanks :)